# How do you get an EditText to stretch based on the text in the box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a custom date picker (not using `DatePickers` because they would not fit on the small screen).  The month, day and year are all custom views called NumberPickers.

The problem is that I need the buttons on the date picker to stretch and the edit text to stretch based on the text in the Edit Text. The number pickers are all added programmatically.

The number picker layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutNumberPicker"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.mycompany.ediary.NumberPickerButton
    android:id="@+id/increment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/timepicker_up_btn" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timepicker_input"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:background="@drawable/timepicker_input"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<com.mycompany.ediary.NumberPickerButton
    android:id="@+id/decrement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/timepicker_down_btn" />
```

However, the `EditText`s are all the same width instead of being stretched for the size of the text.  As you can see, the year is cut off. I'm not sure how to get it to stretch.  When I set the width of the `EditText`s to be a set size and not wrap_content, the buttons do not stretch to the same width (they are 9 Patches).

[image: View from a note 4]

The code to display the month, day and year is:

```
LinearLayout layoutWidgets = new LinearLayout(con);
    layoutWidgets.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    /*****Set width of Date******/
    layoutWidgets.setMinimumWidth(185);
    layoutWidgets.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    /*****Set width of Date******/
    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if (GlobalVars.subjectLeftToRight == 1) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btnDTPicker.getId());
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, lblQuestionText.getId());
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        //params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    } else {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btnDTPicker.getId());
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, lblQuestionText.getId());
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        //params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    layoutWidgets.setWeightSum(1);
    layoutWidgets.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The month:

```
layoutMonth = new LinearLayout(con);
    layoutMonth.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    layoutMonth.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutMonth.setMinimumWidth(95);
    pickerMonth = new NumberPicker(con);
    pickerMonth.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    pickerMonth.setupText(147);// [Blank]
    pickerMonth.setTag(tagMonthPicker);
    pickerMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pickerMonth.setFormatter(NumberPicker.TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER);
    pickerMonth.setRange(1, 12, GlobalVars.calNamesShort);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lparams.weight = .3f;
    pickerMonth.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    layoutMonth.addView(pickerMonth);
```

The day:

```
layoutDay = new LinearLayout(con);
    layoutDay.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    layoutDay.setTag(tagDayLayout);
    layoutDay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutDay.setMinimumWidth(95);
    layoutDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    pickerDay = new NumberPicker(con);
    pickerDay.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    pickerDay.setupText(147);// [Blank]
    pickerDay.setTag(tagDayPicker);
    pickerDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pickerDay.setFormatter(NumberPicker.TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER);
        lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.weight = .3f;
    pickerDay.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    layoutDay.addView(pickerDay);
```

The Year:

```
layoutYear = new LinearLayout(con);
    layoutYear.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    layoutYear.setTag(tagYearLayout);
    layoutYear.setMinimumWidth(95);
    layoutYear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutYear.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    pickerYear = new NumberPicker(con);
    pickerYear.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
    pickerYear.setupText(147);// [Blank]
    pickerYear.setTag(tagYearPicker);
    pickerYear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pickerYear.setRange(minYear, maxYear);

        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    /** width of year **/
    lparams.weight = .4f;
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    pickerYear.setLayoutParams(params);
    layoutYear.addView(pickerYear);
```

Adding the views to the layout:

```
layoutWidgets.addView(layoutMonth);
layoutWidgets.addView(layoutDay);
layoutWidgets.addView(layoutYear);
```

**EDIT**

```
public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mContext = context;

    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker, this, true);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    InputFilter inputFilter = new NumberPickerInputFilter();
    mNumberInputFilter = new NumberRangeKeyListener();
    mIncrementButton = (NumberPickerButton)findViewById(R.id.increment);
    mIncrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mIncrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mIncrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);
    mDecrementButton = (NumberPickerButton)findViewById(R.id.decrement);
    mDecrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mDecrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mDecrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);

    mText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
    /*** set size of number picker **/
    //mText.setWidth(Math.round(convertFromDp(80)));
    mText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { inputFilter });
    mText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);


    if (!isEnabled()) {
        setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public float convertFromDp(int input) {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return ((input - 0.5f) / scale);
}
```

Comment: @DerGolem  You're referring to native datepickers?

Comment: @DerGolem It's just not an option.

Comment: OR you could simply use a **2 digit** year. No more millennium bug for about a millennium...

Comment: @DerGolum - Again, not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the parent linear layout is overriding the size. I would recommend you do not use wrap_content, but use a specific dp and set the gravity to center (or center_horizontal) so that your UI is consistent in look and feel. Assuming you fix the problem, if you let it wrap, that means the buttons will move around!

To fix the problem can you post the layout params of the parent linear layouts?

EDIT: After reviewing your code once again

So going back to your original question. Looking at your parent of a single date picker, you have three children vertically oriented `NumberButton`, `EditText`, `NumberButton`. Set the width of the parent to `wrap_content`, the width of both `NumberButton`s to `match_parent`, and the width of the `EditText` to `wrap_content`. This should now make the `EditText` the controlling factor of the width, with the `NumberButtons` expanding to however wide, provided there is not a constraint imposed upon the parent's width (not enough space available, explicit size set). If you do this for one set inside a parent linear layout set to horizontal, for example, this would work. If it's not at this point, then it is a problem with the parent layout not the layout of these themselves.

Comment: You have all the layouts.  There are no layout params of the parent.

Comment: Ahh, in this case you're parent linear layouts are all `fill_parent` which means they'll stretch as much as they can. Try setting match parent on their parent, or a hard coded value and see if that changes the edit text widths. Also I'm not sure, what is `pickerMonth = new NumberPicker(con);` reffering to--which view is this?

Comment: letting the layout width of layoutWidgets to Match_Parent wiped out the time picker.

Comment: Why are you using RelativeLayout rules for LinearLayout params? Did you try using a hardcoded value that is reasonable to fit all the children?

Comment: Do you have xml for the parent of all these?

Comment: no there is no xml for this parent - all are done in code, and no layout params are set.  The parent of the layoutWidget is a Relative Layout, that's why there are relative layout params used.  The time picker and the layout picker are both added to this Relative Layout.

Comment: Following your suggestions in your answer edit, nothing changed in the way the date picker was presented.  :(

Comment: I found it!  the NumberPicker EditText was being set to a certain width.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Awesome! Sometimes its just finding that needle in the haystack!

Comment: agreed.  But I think you got the EditText to size up based on text.